# Wordpress dropdown works locally but not on server

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

I have the exact same menu hierarchy on both my local WordPress site and the one I transferred to my server. Both the sites are exactly identical except for the fact that the WordPress version on my live server is 5.5 but on my local server, it is 5.4.2.

To alleviate this, I updated my local WordPress installation to 5.5 as well and the dropdown menu stopped working locally too.

Menu dropdowns are only working on my local site and not on the server despite having basically the same hierarchy. Each time I hover over a menu element that is supposed to show a dropdown, it just sits there doing nothing.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

For those of you wondering what happening, WordPress 5.5 has changed the way JQuery works with WP and that is inevitably going to break some themes and/or plugins.

To resolve this, just install the Enable JQuery Migrate Helper plugin and you'll be good to go.